# How to pass and return 2d array to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix, return

I'm trying to change a 2D array values in different function so it suits my need.
For an example in the code below I'm trying to change the Matrix to reflexive by changing the to "1" .

I have an issue returning the new array and replace it with the old one in the main program so I can use it again.

```
int reflexive(int m, int n, int matrix[100][100])
{

 for(int i = 1;i <= m; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if(i == j)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j] != 1)
                matrix[i][j] = 1;
        }
 return matrix;
     }
   }
 }
int main()
{
    int  matrix[100][100];
    int m , n;
    for(int i = 1;i <= m; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            cin>>matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    matrix[m][n] = reflexive(m,n,matrix);
 return 0;
}
```

I want to fix this code so it can return the full new 2D array to the main program.

Comment: You could just define a `struct` (that holds the array) and/or use `std::vector`

Comment: Open to the chapter in your C++ book that explains how to use `std::array`, and learn how to use this class. Nearly identical semantics to a native array, but with object-like semantics that avoids all the pitfalls here. And although returning large arrays, by value, is somewhat inefficient, that's something to be dealt with later. For the purposes of learning C++ this will be fine.

Comment: There's no new array, the function is modifying the array you're passing.

Comment: ** UnholySheep**
Can you tell me how to use the std::vector ?

Comment: Use Boost matrices or create a matrix class  yourself. You can use `std::vector` to provide underlying storage.

Comment: Indexes of an array are in [0, N), not [1,N]. And you haven't initialized `m` and `n`.

Comment: You could pass in a lambda that takes a (int dim1, int dim2) to access the element in the 2D array.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: returning large arrays by value isn't inefficient in practice. As far as I know all extant compilers do return value optimization.

Comment: `int matrix[100][100]` in `reflexive()` isn't passed as copy (as you might expect). In C++ (and C), array arguments (and return values) _always_ decay to a pointer. So, it looks like `matrix[100][100]`, it can be used like `matrix[100][100]` but actually it is [`int (*matrix)[100]`](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*matrix%29%5B100%5D). (Click the link if you want to see it spelled out.) This means, any change on `matrix` done in `reflexive()` becomes effective to the `matrix` argument which was passed on caller side. In other words: You don't have a "return issue". You always "return" results...

Answer (score 1):

In your function `reflexive` the return statement is inside the loop. This causes that the function is terminated immediately when the return statement is reached. If you would proper format your code you would be able to see this behavior easily.

Further note, that the first element in an array has the index 0 and the index of the last element is the the size of the array -1. This is, because the array index is the element "offset". This means that

```
a[i]
```

and

```
*(a + i)
```

access the same array element.

```
for(int i = 1;i <= m; i++)      // <--- should be  for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++) // <--- should be for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        if(i == j)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j] != 1)
                matrix[i][j] = 1;
        }
        return matrix;          // <--- here the function is terminated
    }
}
```

An array is passed to a function by a pointer and **not** by value. This means if a formal parameter of a function is an array, then not all the values of the actual parameter are copied to the array. There is only passed a pointer  to the values of the paramter to the function.
Because of that you do not need any return value in your case.

The following code should do what you want:

```
int reflexive(int m, int n, int matrix[100][100])
{
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(i == j)
            {
                if(matrix[i][j] != 1)
                    matrix[i][j] = 1; // <----- write to the data by pointer
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int  matrix[100][100];
    ......
    reflexive(m,n,matrix);
    ......
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 1;i <= m; i++)` is probably not what he wants.

Comment: @super Thank you. I was sloppy

Answer (score 0):

Use  `vector<vector<int>>` and pass it by reference

Answer (score -2):

Using an array here is tedious and error-prone. Therefore:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<int> > reflexive(std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size; j++){
....

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix(100, std::vector<int>(100));
    int m , n; //<<whereever they come from I guess? Saw no cin in your code. Have no set value right now.
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for(int j =0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin>>matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
#include<array>

...

std::array<std::array<int, 100>, 100> matrix;
```

`std::array` is of fixed size, `std::vector` is dynamic. Also learn about `std::list` while you're at it.

In any case, you should find a basic tutorial that talks about them and read all of it. Important standards.

That said, especially if you want to use dynamic sized arrays, you have no guarantee that every sub-array is of the same size ("a *jagged* 2d array), which is somehwat okay in a small program but should be avoided in the big picture, by using a class that ensures this property.

In the case of a matrix, one easy option is to use a library that deals with matrices, like for example Eigen.

edit:

If at some point you need the code above in const-correct:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > reflexive(const std::vector<std::vector<int> >& input)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > output = input;
    ....
    return output;
}
```

(or make it void if it is allowed to modify the original matrix)

Comment: `int **matrix` is not the way to pass a 2D array, even in C.  If the caller tries to pass a 2D array to such a function, the code will not compile.

Comment: @Peter Meant my answer to focus on `vector`, therefore deleted the part about raw arrays.